# Using Prerender-Node with Meteor

Tags: meteor

As an alternative to spiderable, is it possible to use prerender node?

https://github.com/prerender/prerender-node

If so how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Prerenderio with Meteor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322771/how-to-use-prerenderio-with-meteor)

Comment: Recommend to try 3rd party service — [ostr.io](https://ostr.io)

Answer (score 2):

Did you just submit a duplicate question?

Here's my answer to your question [How to use Prerender with Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322771/how-to-use-prerenderio-with-meteor)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26541817/951773

TL;DR version:

> Firstly, remove the spiderable package if you haven't already.
>
> Second, drop this at your server-side code (for example `server/prerenderio.js`):
>
> ```
> // Use Prerender with your token
> var prerenderio = Npm.require('prerender-node').set('prerenderToken', 'YOUR_TOKEN'); 
> // Feed it to middleware! (app.use)
> WebApp.connectHandlers.use(prerenderio);
> ```

Comment: I certainly forgot I asked it before. Thanks :)